# header() redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, redirect

I can't get the Script working. I want a Javascript alert that confirms an action and then a redirect back to my Page. This isn't working:

```
echo "<script>setTimeout(alert('Danke, dein Wunsch wurde eingetragen.'),1);</script>";                  
mail("test@test.de", "Subject", "Hallo, lorem impsum.");
mail("secondtest@test.de", "Subject", "Hallo, lorem impsum.");
header('Location: ../../wishlist.php');`
```

Comment: Define "isn't working". What is or is not happening.

Comment: That's not how PHP works. You need to learn about the server/client relationship.

Comment: You are not clear about interaction of javascript to PHP here.  Are you sending email in response to an AJAX call?  If not, I am not sure why you would perform any messaging via javascript, as by the time javascript is written to the page and executed, your headers have already been sent to the browser.  Why not simply output the message on the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: *Um...* why 2x `mail(...)` ? Remove one. *Plus*, outputting before header; no go.

Comment: If you want to use JS *and* redirect, you can always use `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com">` instead of `header()` - It's a quick fix.

Comment: JohnConde the redirect is not working. Everything else is working fine.
MikeBrant Sorry I didn't get your Idea.
@Fred-ii- Because I want to notify two person. I will try your HTML Redirect.

Comment: The HTML redirect will work. @runepiper PHP does not allow to output before `header()`

Comment: Please don't post your solution within the question.  Post your solution below as an answer and then "accept" it as soon as you're allowed.

Comment: Since the OP used [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514027/header-redirect-doesnt-work#comment34256364_22514027) as his/her solution, I should be posting it as an answer then (?) in order to close the question. @Sparky

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it doesn't matter as long as the question is not edited to post the answer within.  Only the "answers" section is for posting answers.  So post yours too.  Maybe the OP will accept it.  Maybe you'll get up-votes.  Whatever... you have enough rep to know how this site works.

Comment: Agreed. The upvotes are ok but that's not what I'm about. @Sparky I just want to close it properly.

Comment: runepiper, please "accept" an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You cant output anything before the header call. From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

```
echo "<script>setTimeout(alert('Danke, dein Wunsch wurde eingetragen.'),1);</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It has already been stated that you cannot output before [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), so I won't repeat it.

(*To close the question*)

OP [`posted in an edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22514027/4) which was later modified by Sparky:

*"UPDATE: Ok for my Problem this did work for me:*

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../../wishlist.php\">";
```

*I've used it instead of the header and after the alert."*

as the solution provided by [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514027/header-redirect-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment34256364_22514027):

*"If you want to use JS and redirect, you can always use `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com">` instead of `header()` - It's a quick fix."*

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com">
```

In your case as you posted in your question earlier, use:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../../wishlist.php\">";
```